# How do I get a valid connection string in .NET Core Web App?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

This is my code but when I run it, I get a connection string that is always `null`. I also have the EntityFrameworkCore and SqlServer NuGet packages installed to.

The error I get is this:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'
> _connectionStrings was null.

***appSettings.Development.json***

```
{
    "Logging": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Information",
                "Microsoft": "Warning",
                "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
            }
    },

    "ConnectionStrings": {
            "MyDataContext": "[actual connection string]"
        }
}
```

***Startup.cs***

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
        
        services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDataContext")));

    }
}
```

***ConnectionStrings.cs***

```
public class ConnectionStrings
{
    public string MyDataContext { get; set; }
}
```

***MyDataContext***

```
public class MyDataContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDataContext(DbContextOptions<MyDataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

***Index.cs.html***

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ConnectionStrings _connectionStrings;


    public IndexModel(ConnectionStrings connectionStrings)
    {
        _connectionStrings = connectionStrings;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

        string connectionString = _connectionStrings.MyDataContext;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            sb.Append(dr[0]);
        }

        conn.Close();

    ...
        // Do more stuff with the sql data here
    }
}
```

I also get a null reference to the object connection string. What am I missing?

**Edit**

I have added the `constructor` and now get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'MyProject.ConnectionStrings' while attempting to activate
> 'MyProject.Pages.IndexModel'.

All the classes have `namespace` of `MyProject` with the exception of `MyProject.Pages` for the `IndexModel` page.

***Solved***

```
    private readonly ConnectionStrings _connectionStrings;
    
    public IndexModel(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionStrings)
    {
        _connectionStrings = connectionStrings.Value;
    }
```

Understaing DI and the Options pattern are important and need further reading.

Comment: How's your host setup? Maybe you arent reading or deploying  appSettings.Development.json?

Comment: this is a local dev test. i think i am missing like `_connectionString = connectionString.Value` somewhere bt not sure where

Comment: `Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDataContext")` can directly fetch your connection string that you can inject using your own approach.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73084200/edit) your question to include the constructor for your `IndexModel` class. Does it include a `ConnectionStrings` parameter so that dependency injection can pass in an instance? Does it use that parameter to set `this._connectionStrings`? Otherwise `_connectionStrings` will be `null` because it's not set to anything else.

Comment: You're getting null reference exception because it is null. You're not assigning any value to the object

Comment: What is the constructor supposed to look like?

Comment: The edit has been added in

Comment: I found the problem. First dependency injections are very important with the constructor and the edit with error above occurs because I need to use IOptions<ConnectionStrings> in the constuctor

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, The `Appsetting.Development.json` is split file and You must add this file to your configuration in Startup, like.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    return new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

}
```

**So you can add ConnectionString to Development and Production file by Env Environment**

-- Priority for reading section ->
1 - `AppSettings.Json`
2 - `AppSetting.{Env}.Json`